# How to open a dialog outside the iframe

Tags: jquery, user-interface, iframe, dialog

I'm calling a jQueryUI Dialog inside the iframe which looks like this:

[image]

But i need the dialog outside the iframe (like `window.parent ----> open dialog` or something like that).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to initialize the dialog in the `parent` with `autoOpen` set to `false` if thats the case.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false });
```

After you can open it from the iframe by adding `parent.` before the expression:

```
parent.$("#dialog").dialog("open");
```